# read XML tag id from php

Tags: php

i am have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

```
  <Message Id="Language">German</Message>
  <Message Id="LangEnglish">German</Message>

  <Message Id="TopMakeHomepage">
        Mache 4W Consulting Webseite zu deiner Starseite!
  </Message>
  <Message Id="TopLinkEmpSec">
        4W Mitarbeiter
  </Message>
  <Message Id="TopLinkFeedback">
        Feedback
  </Message>
  <Message Id="TopLinkSiteMap">
        Site Map
  </Message>
  <Message Id="TopLinkContactUs">
        Kontakt
  </Message>
  <Message Id="TopSetLangEn">
        ins Englische
  </Message>
  <Message Id="TopSetLangDe">
        ins Deutsche
  </Message>
  <Message Id="TopSetLangEs">
        ins Spanische
  </Message>
  <Message Id="MenuLinks">
        !~|4W Starseite|Company|Über uns|Kontakt|4W anschließen|Services|Kunden Software Entwicklung|Altsystem Neugestalltung &amp; Umwandlung|Altsystem Dokumentation|Daten Umwandlung &amp; Migration|Erstellen von Datenbeschreibungsverzeichnis|System- &amp; Anwendungs Support|Projekt Management &amp; Planunng|Personal Erweiterung|Projekt Ausgliederung|Mitarbeiter Ausbildung|Technologie|Intersystems Caché|M / MUMPS|Zusätzliche Technologien|Methodologie|Feedback|~!
  </Message>
</MsgFile>
```

in this XML file i need to fetch the contents using the tagid . what exactly i need is when i input the 'TopMakeHomepage' i need output as 'Mache 4W Consulting Webseite zu deiner Starseite!' ... 
Please help me to find out this . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($grabUrl);
foreach ($xml->Message as $message) {
    echo $message->attributes()->Id.'<br />';
}
```

Or use [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php), with which you can miss memory leaks when processing large XMLs.

```
$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open($grabUrl);
while ($xml->read()) {
    if ($xml->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'Message')
        echo $xml->getAttribute('Id');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With the [DOM extension](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) it should be something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse = TRUE;
$dom->loadXML($xmlString); // or use ->load('file.xml')
$node = $dom->getElementById('foo');
echo $node->nodeValue;
```

See the manual on

- [`DOMDocument::getElementById`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)  — Searches for an element with a certain id

---

If it doesn't work with `getElementById` (which usually only happens if the DTD doesn't know the id attribute), you can still use [XPath](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to do the query:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//Message[@id = "foo"]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Unlike `getElementById`, an [XPath query](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) always returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). It will be empty if the query didn't find any nodes.

---

If the ID is a real XML ID, you can also use the id() function in XPath

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('id("foo")');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

See [Simplify PHP DOM XML parsing - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405117/simplify-php-dom-xml-parsing-how/3405651#3405651) for more details on XML IDs.

Answer (score 2):

For SimpleXML this should do the trick:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFileLoc);
foreach ($xml->Message as $msg)
{
    echo $msg['Id'];
}
```