# Take the content of the XML tags using DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I need to take the content of the tags (in the XML file) and save them in a MySql database, using PHP.

My supervisor asked me to use DOM, but everything I do isn't workin'.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<BIENS>
<BIEN>
   <CODE_SOCIETE>0024</CODE_SOCIETE>
   <CODE_SITE>02</CODE_SITE>
   <TYPE_OFFRE>1</TYPE_OFFRE>
   <NO_ASP>3637017</NO_ASP>
   <NO_DOSSIER>00059</NO_DOSSIER>
   <NO_MANDAT>6523</NO_MANDAT>
</BIEN>
<BIEN>
....
</BIEN>
</BIENS>
```

Comment: Your example is not in XML syntax. Please make sure to format it correctly as code block.

Comment: why not show us the parts that you are doing that are not working?

Comment: Why don't you post the code that you're using, then we can see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Basic usage example for your XML to iterate over all BIEN elements and it's child nodes:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->load('file.xml');
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('BIEN') as $bien) {
    foreach($bien->childNodes as $childNode) {
        echo $childNode->tagName . '=>' . $childNode->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Should be trivial to exchange the `echo`'ing code to insert into your database instead.

[Basic usage of DOM has been covered extensively on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DOM+php+xml), so you should not have a problem finding [further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405117/simplify-php-dom-xml-parsing-how/3405651#3405651) [usage examples (linked are mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+xml+DOM+php).

Answer (score 0):

Try using SimpleXml. This way, you can simply loop over the BIENs with foreach, and get the items like `$sitecode = $biens->CODE_SITE`

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleXML, it is pretty easy to use it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php