# How can I get PHP simplexml to save < as itself instead of &lt;

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Basically I have a script that updates an xml document in various places... However, I need the text to be in CDATA... So I attempted this:

```
                $PrintQuestion->content->multichoice->feedback->hint->Passage->Paragraph->addChild('TextFragment', '<![CDATA[' . $value[0] . ']]>');
```

Unfortunately when I save the XML back to file, the < and > in cdata come up as their respective < and $gt; codes is there a way to avoid this?

**Note: Our parser doesn't know how to read the `&lt;` and `&gt;` codes, so this is a serious issue**

after doing a print_r of my simple_xml object, the < appears as itself in the source code!

It must be the domsave that is converting it into the entity code... any ideas how to disable this?

```
        //Convert SimpleXML element to DOM and save
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = false;
        $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
        $dom->save($filename);
```

Comment: SimpleXML is, like the name implies, for simple modifications. If you need proper control over the Nodes, you should consider using DOM. DOM has a method to create CDATA sections.

Comment: Your parser understands CDATA sections but not `&lt;`? That's odd.  You might want to update your parser...

Comment: It's a project for work... I have no control over the parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, SimpleXML is very limited in the control it gives you over the DOM nodes. Here is an example on how to replace a [DOMText](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php) node with a [DOMCDATASection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php) node.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML('<root><a>foo</a></root>');
$a = $dom->documentElement->childNodes->item(0);
$a->replaceChild(
    $dom->createCDATASection('bar'),
    $a->childNodes->item(0)
);
echo $dom->saveXml($a); // <a><![CDATA[bar]]></a>
```

For a lengthy example on how to use DOM [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405117/simplify-php-dom-xml-parsing-how/3405651) and [some more here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+dom)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function before sending it to your parser? It will convert `&lt` and `&gt` back to `<` and `>`

Answer (score 1):

The parser can't cope with CDATA sections? In that case it is not an XML parser, so you need to write a tool that generates an XML-like output instead of an XML tool. (Or fix the parser so it becomes an XML parser)