# SimpleXML, CDATA and HTML entities

Tags: php, flash, simplexml

I'm tearing my hair out trying to work with "simple" XML for the first time. I'm building a small CMS for a Flash based site and the content is held in an XML file. My problem is that many of the copy fields are XML CDATA fields. on the one hand, with:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

I can pull the data out of that node and the CDATA tags are stripped. My issues come with trying to save the data with:

```
file_put_contents($file, $xml->asXML());
```

Problems are:

a) tags are interpreted with their HTML entity equivalents. I don't want this to happen. I gather this is coming from the asXML method because even if I do an html_entity_decode on the $_POST data it's still being converted.

b) because of the above, there's no way to add the CDATA tags because they also have their charachters converted.

SimpleXML so far has been anything but simple for me. Has anyone ever run into this?

Comment: IMO, it's a common misconception that the *simple* in SimpleXml is supposed to mean *simple to use*. It rather means you should use if for simple XML applications. And for anything else, use a proper API, like DOM.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Having only ever had to deal with databases with my data I wasn't even aware of the DOM class. This looks much more like what I need. CDATA functions! Awesome, thanks for the quick and simple response. BTW, the simple thing was a really bad joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this seemed to be exactly what I needed to do:

[How to keep DOMDocument from saving < as &lt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424084/how-to-keep-domdocument-from-saving-as-lt)

Although pouring over the manual for the DOM api has given me something new I'd like to learn for future use.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used simpleXML before, but if your problem is that your data is being saved as XML encoded, then Flash can convert XMLEncoded data to XML objects natively. You can load in your data and just pass it to an new XML object like so:

`var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader( new URLRequest('./test.xml') );
ldr.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, handleLoaded );`

function handleLoaded( e:Event ) : void
{
    var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
}

and you will have a native Flash XML object.

If you are using AS2, then you will need to use the LoadVars object to load the data, but you will need to use the `onData` (not `onLoad`) event to grab your XML encoded string and pass it to the XML object.

not sure if this solves your problem, but it might be helpful.