# XML Entity not defined in Chrome

Tags: php, xml

My browser is telling me:

```
error on line 2 at column 308899: Entity 'ntilde' not defined
```

and the specific line is in my xml as:

```
<LastName>Trevi&ntilde;o</LastName>
```

the name was originally `Treviño`, but it was modified via php's `htmlentities` function.

What can I do to get php and xml to play nicely?

---

*Using Chrome 19 on Mac.*

Comment: why are you calling a function named `htmlentities` on XML?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822774/php-is-htmlentities-sufficient-for-creating-xml-safe-values

Comment: I would have gladly used `xmlentities` if such a function existed :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently using `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` in tandem does the trick.

```
htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually generating XML, or HTML? They're not the same thing. HTML defines a bunch of entities (IIRC) whereas XML has very few "built-in" - just a few like `&amp;` and `&lt;`.

Why both using the entity when you can just use the text directly? Simply make sure you're consistent about the encoding you use (UTF-8 would be a good bet).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to encode the tilde character in XML. It will throw errors. Best thing to do in this case might be to wrap the text in CDATA.

```
<LastName><![CDATA[Trevi&ntilde;o]]></LastName>
```

Comment: this works, but when I pass that to `SimpleXML`s `addChild` it ruins the `CDATA` by replacing the `<>` with `&lt;&gt;`

Comment: Check out this link about exactly that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424084/how-to-keep-domdocument-from-saving-as-lt

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify encoding for htmlentities

```
htmlentities($string,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be: Treviño.
An Entity may be missing from your DTD file?
something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Customer
[
<!ENTITY ntilde "&#241;">
]>

<Customer>
<LastName>Trevi&ntilde;o</LastName>
</Customer>
```