# fetch data from elements with same id in a HTML document

Tags: php, php-parser

I am using PHP DOMDocument class to parse the HTML file, and using the code,

```
$dom =new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($file_path);
$dom->getElementById("my_id")
```

to fetch the data of the element with the ID "my_id", but the problem is the HTML document is containing multiple elements with same ID, and i want the data in all that elements..
The HTML code,

```
<div id="my_id">
     phone number 123
</div>
<div id="my_id">
     address somewhere 
</div>
 <div id="my_id">
     date of birth
</div>
```

i know the ID is unique, but here the case is like that..
in this case will getElementById() will return an array..

Comment: An `id` has to be unique throughout the entire html document (afaik there are no exceptions allowed). see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: Your HTML will not be valid if 2 or more elements have the same id.

Comment: "Will getElementById return an array?"...  Why not try it out?

Comment: yeah, i know that..but the document that i am parsing is having structure like that..i dont know.. who wrote there CSS.. :D.. but we will try it out @Pekka

Comment: getElementById() will not return an array. Since HTML marks `id` as an identifier the document is invalid and the thing parsing the document can do more or less anything, including: reject the document entirely, return the first element with that id, return the last element with that id, ....

Answer (score 1):

No, if anything [`getElementById()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) will return a [`DOMElement`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php). In case of multiple returned nodes, results would be a [`DOMNodeList`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), but that doesnt apply here.

Furthermore, [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) will not recognize your IDs until you validate the Document against a DTD or Schema file that defines the id attribute as an actual XML ID attribute, which is different from other attributes. That's why [`DOMAttr` has a method `isId`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domattr.isid.php) and 
XML requires IDs to be of unique value. As VolkerK pointed out in the comments, when using `loadHTMLFile`, this validation will occur automatically.

See my answer to [***Simplify PHP DOM XML parsing - how?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405117/simplify-php-dom-xml-parsing-how/3405651#3405651) for more detailed information.

Comment: Mostly true but; "the HTML file", there _could_ be different rules for HTML ;-) And loadHTMLFile() causes the html dtd to be used, i.e. `id` _is_ an identifier.

Comment: @Volker I'm not sure `loadHTMLFile` will `validateOnParse` automatically and I left any reference to the load method out intentionally.

Comment: I've tested it. getElementById() worked and isId() returned true for $e->getAttributeNode('id')->isId() without further doing (not even a doctype for the html document).

Comment: @VolkerK okay, but what do you suggest I should change about my answer? Because `loadHTML` validating automatically doesnt falsify that a validation against a DTD has to happen at some point. That's explicitly stated in the manual for `getElementById()`

Comment: The "Furthermore, DOM will not recognize your IDs until..." reads as if Harish needs to _do_ something to get getElementByID() to work - while there's no way around that `id` is an identifier and the document is invalid when loaded via loadhtmlfile(). But my main concern was with your first version only referring to xml - and "even that" didn't keep me from up-voting your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  You'll find that the value of the getElementById is undefined, though you will be able to find out that the element is a DIV

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a XPath Query for the ID-attribute can help.

Answer (score 0):

If there's absolutely no way you (or somebody else) can fix the incoming data (which, as has been pointed out, is the only really right thing to do) This might be a case where [SimpleHTMLDOM's](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) more lenient parsing turns out to be fruitful.

I haven't tried how it deals with this, but I *could* imagine that

```
foreach ($html->find('div[id=my_id]') as $element)
 echo "Found ".$element->id."<br>";
```

works as needed.

Comment: $dom->getElementById("my_id")->nodeName; gave me the Node name as "div" but other functions were not working... i will try the above code..