# DOM parser that allows HTML5-style </ in <script> tag

Tags: php, dom, html

**Update**: `html5lib` (bottom of question) seems to get close, I just need to improve my understanding of how it's used.

I am attempting to find an HTML5-compatible DOM parser for PHP 5.3. In particular, I need to access the following HTML-like CDATA within a script tag:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="foo">
    <table><tr><td>${name}</td></tr></table>
</script>
```

Most parsers will end parsing prematurely because HTML 4.01 [ends script tag parsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#notes-specifying-data) when it finds ETAGO (`</`) inside a `<script>` tag. However, HTML5 [allows for `</`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) before `</script>`. All of the parsers I have tried so far have either failed, or they are so poorly documented that I haven't figured out if they work or not.

My requirements:

1. Real parser, not regex hacks.
2. Ability to load full pages or HTML fragments.
3. Ability to pull script *contents* back out, selecting by the tag's id attribute.

Input:

```
<script id="foo"><td>bar</td></script>
```

Example of failing output (no closing `</td>`):

```
<script id="foo"><td>bar</script>
```

Some parsers and their results:

### [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (fails)

Source:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML('<script id="foo"><td>bar</td></script>');
echo $d->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : td in Entity, line: 1 in /home/adam/public_html/2010/10/26/dom.php on line 5
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><script id="foo"><td>bar</script></head></html>
```

### [FluentDOM](http://fluentdom.github.com/) (fails)

Source:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');
require_once 'FluentDOM/src/FluentDOM.php';
$html = "<html><head></head><body><script id='foo'><td></td></script></body></html>";
echo FluentDOM($html, 'text/html');
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head></head><body><script id="foo"><td></script></body></html>
```

### [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) (fails)

Source:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');

require_once 'phpQuery.php';

phpQuery::newDocumentHTML(<<<EOF
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="foo">
<td>test</td>
</script>
EOF
);
```

echo (string)pq('#foo');

Output:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="foo">
<td>test
</script>
```

### [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) (passes)

Possibly promising. Can I get at the contents of the `script#foo` tag?

Source:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');

include 'HTML5/Parser.php';

$html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><script id='foo'><td></td></script></body></html>";
$d = HTML5_Parser::parse($html);

echo $d->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<html><head></head><body><script id="foo"><td></td></script></body></html>
```

Comment: Note: when you try to parse HTML via loadHTML, DOM based libraries will use libxml's HTML parser module. If you load your snippet above with loadXML instead, there will be no errors, but of course, the page is expected to be valid XHTML then. Also see [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) but basically all DOM based parsers will likely produce the same results here.

Comment: +1 for a good question. I wonder if it would be possible to use HTML comments or a CDATA block to delimit the code in the script tag, as one would do for Javascript? Or would that also get included in the output from the template?

Comment: If html5lib passes isn't that the answer to this question?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and apparently you can hack your way trough this by loading the document as XML, and save it as HTML :)

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadXML('<script id="foo"><td>bar</td></script>');
echo $d->saveHTML();
```

But of course the markup must be error-free for loadXML to work.

Comment: Also note that this will break on HTML5 elements that aren't self closing (link, img, br, etc) since those are illegal in XML.

Answer (score 7):

I just find out (in my case).

try to change parameters option of `loadHTML` using `LIBXML_SCHEMA_CREATE` in `DOMDocument`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
//$dom->loadHTML($buffer, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$dom->loadHTML($buffer, LIBXML_SCHEMA_CREATE);
```

Comment: This actually handled it. Are there side effects/limitations?

Answer (score 5):

Re: html5lib

You click on the download tab and [download the PHP version of the parser](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/downloads/detail?name=html5lib-php-0.1.tar.gz&can=2&q=).

You untar the archive in a local folder

```
 tar -zxvf html5lib-php-0.1.tar.gz
 x html5lib-php-0.1/
 x html5lib-php-0.1/VERSION
 x html5lib-php-0.1/docs/
 ... etc
```

You change directories and create a file named hello.php

```
cd html5lib-php-0.1
touch hello.php
```

You place the following PHP code in `hello.php`

```
$html = '<html><head></head><body>
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="foo">
<table><tr><td>${name}</td></tr></table>
</script> 
</body></html>';
$dom = HTML5_Parser::parse($html); 
var_dump($dom->saveXml()); 
echo "\nDone\n";
```

You run `hello.php` from the command line

```
php hello.php
```

The parser will parse the document tree, and return a DOMDocument object, which can be manipulated as any other DOMDocument object.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. How can I dig down to the contents of the script tag, searching by id?

Comment: It's a standard DOMDocument object.  If you're not comfortable with the DOMDocument, then call the saveXML method (as above) and create a SimpleXml object out of it.  If you're not comfortable with Simple XML, you should <a href="http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php">read the manual</a>

Comment: Added html5lib to [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: @Alan I hit a wall (well, got mildly annoyed) when I couldn't get `$dom->getElementById()` to work on the resulting DOMDocument. I ended up working around the problem, but I'd be interested to know why it fails and if it can be made to work.

Comment: Because DOMDocument is a confusing pile of over engineered poorly document XML processing?  For getElementById to work with DOM documents you need to have a DTD that says which attribute name is an ID, or explicitly set which attribute name on an element is an ID. Whenever I have a DOMDocument I save out an XML string to feed into SimpleXML, and then use the xPath functions to get at what I want.

Comment: @Adam  More info on why your call wasn't working.  Sort of went beyond the 600 character limit :) http://alanstorm.com/domdocument_php_stop

Comment: @Adam no problem. You might also be interested in my answer to [Simplify PHP DOM XML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405117/simplify-php-dom-xml-parsing-how/3405651#3405651). Also, the id attributes in DOM example in your blog post are not unique, so even if they were proper xml:id attributes, the XML wouldnt be valid.

Answer (score 5):

FluentDOM uses the DOMDocument but blocks loading notices and warnings. It does not have an own parser. You can add your own loaders (For example one that uses the html5lib).

Answer (score 4):

I added comment tags (`<!-- ... -->`) in my jQuery template blocks (CDATA blocks also failed) and DOMDocument did not touch the internal HTML.

Then, before I used the jQuery templates, I wrote a script to remove the comments.

```
$(function() {
    $('script[type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"]').text(function() {
        // The comment node in this context is actually a text node.
        return $.trim($(this).text()).replace(/^<!--([\s\S]*)-->$/, '$1');
    });
});
```

Not ideal, but I wasn't sure of a better workaround.

Comment: I mean... i'm using <% %> tags (for underscore templating) and commenting it doesnt work. I'd love to prevent XMLDocument to parse script inner texts/htmls

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact problem.

PHP Dom Document parses the html inside a script tag and that can actually lead to a completely different dom.

Since I didn't want to use another library than DomDocument. I wrote a few lines that strips any script content, then you do what ever you need to do with dom document and afterwards you put that script content back.

Obviously the script content isn't available to your dom object because it's empty.

With the following lines of php code you can 'fix' this problem. Be warned that script tags in scripts tags will cause bug.

```
$scripts = array();
// this will select all script tags non-greedy. If you have a script tag in your script tag, it will cause problems.
preg_match_all("/((<script.*>)(.*))\/script>/sU", $html, $scripts);
// Make content of scripts empty
$html = str_replace($scripts[3], '', $html);

// Do DOM Document stuff here

// Put script contents back
$html = str_replace($scripts[2], $scripts[1], $html);
```

I hope this will help some people :-).

Comment: This is almost a good solution. However, it doesn't work when the script tags have no attributes that distinguish them from each other.