# PHP: DOMDocument loadHTML returns an error when using HTML5 tags

Tags: php, dom, html, domdocument

Such as [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section).  Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument errors/warnings on html5-tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090667/php-domdocument-errors-warnings-on-html5-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this issue with PHP's DOMDoc and XSL functions. You basically have to load the document as XML. Thats the only way I got the `<video>` tag to work.

Update:
You can also try adding elements & entities to the `<!DOCTYPE html5 >` as long as `$doc->resolveExternals = true`.

Comment: But then I have to use only well-formed XML. :/

Comment: Html5 is supposed to be well formed :P

You can try $doc->resolveExternals = true; and then put the html5 tags you need in the <!DOCTYPE html5 [<!ELEMENT element-name ANY>] >, DomDoc will obey doc-types

Comment: @James HTML5 does not have to be well formed XML. You can still use self closing tags without the `/>`, eg `<img src="foo.jpg">`

Comment: @Phil Yes HTML5 does have to be well formed XML, and the empty-closed-tag is valid XML [w3 eetag](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-eetag)

Comment: @James Just to clarify. HTML5 is not XML nor a variant. Parsing it as such will almost certainly lead to errors. In XML, empty tags *must* be self closing using `/>`. In HTML5, there is no such rule. Empty tags *may* be expressed in either format, eg `<img>` and `<img />`. An HTML5 document may only be parsed as XML (through syntax compatibility only) if all empty tags are expressed as self closing. As either is valid, you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @Phil Your correct, Html5 is not Xhtml so it's not strictly to abide by xml's rules, but as a best practices you should write XML compatible HTML tags to ease using xml/document technologies.

Comment: @James Rather than trying to parse a non-XML document as XML, I think it would be better for the DOM parser to be updated to handle the new doctype. Your suggestion to use externals is the best interim solution IMO

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've tried the library ultimately pointed to in this answer:

[DOM parser that allows HTML5-style </ in <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029341/dom-parser-that-allows-html5-style-in-script-tag)

Html5lib solved the same issue you're experiencing for me (it was the `<aside>` and `<nav>` tags triggering my issues)

I was using this to parse html fragments, and the advantage is that it was a drop-in replacement for DOMDocument, as currently it uses DOMDocument as the output object, so no other functionality was broken in my implementation.

There is a note in the documentation that they are looking to move away from DOMDocument in the future.

html5lib for PHP can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/downloads/detail?name=html5lib-php-0.1.tar.gz&can=2&q=

In the [answer linked to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029341/dom-parser-that-allows-html5-style-in-script-tag), there are further details on usage.

Answer (score 1):

try to ignore the error:

In my cases, I have several "widgets" in several files which acts as templates. For instance:
template_header.html
template_footer.html

```
<?php
//Load header
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('template_header.html');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodelist = $xpath->query('div[class="template-widget"]');
foreach($nodelist as $node){
    echo $dom->saveHTML($node);
}   
?>
```

Note that $dom->loadhtmlfile has and '@' to ognore the error.