# PHP DOMDocument errors/warnings on html5-tags

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I've been attempting to parse HTML5-code so I can set attributes/values within the code, but it seems DOMDocument(PHP5.3) doesn't support tags like `<nav>` and `<section>`.

Is there any way to parse this as HTML in PHP and manipulate the code?

---

Code to reproduce:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>first
    <li>second
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  ...
</section>
</body>
</html>");
```

---

Error

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag
>   nav invalid in Entity, line: 4 in
>   /home/wbkrnl/public_html/new-mvc/1.php
>   on line 17
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag
>   section invalid in Entity, line: 10 in
>   /home/wbkrnl/public_html/new-mvc/1.php
>   on line 17

Comment: Ops, for me `loadHTML($HTML5)` returns FALSE (failure)! I need to change the new tags to DIVs... It is not only a problem of "warnings" on my screen.

Comment: This issue had been reported for PHP at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60021 which in turn spawned a feature request in the underlying libxml2: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761534

Answer (score 237, accepted):

No, there is no way of specifying a particular doctype to use, or to modify the requirements of the existing one.

Your best workable solution is going to be to disable error reporting with [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML('...');
libxml_clear_errors();
```

Comment: Ops, for me `loadHTML($HTML5)` returns FALSE (failure)! I need to change the new tags to DIVs...

Comment: Any reason __*php7*__'s built-into DOM parser _still_ can't handle HTML5? It's been 6 years since this answer was submitted.

Comment: @SuperCat It's all dependant on the underlying libxml library.

Comment: --- not to mention HTML5 isn't XML, never was, has been, nor will be...

Comment: **Update 2019**: The warning is still fired however `loadHTML` now actually accept HTML5 tags.

Comment: @user10351292 since which version? Can't find a changelog for libxml2. As of libxml2 version 2.9.10, still have to use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` to avoid having it throw an exception on HTML5 tags. (Found one more reason to hate PHP.)

Comment: **2022** *still* not support HTML 5 (tested with PHP 8.2 on Windows). However, no one mentioned about `LIBXML_NOERROR` option?

Comment: This is a great solution, @vee. Thank you very much. I used `$DOMDocument -> loadHTML($HTML_String, LIBXML_NOERROR);` on an HTML String which contained `<section>` and the Warning disappeared.

Comment: It's probably best practice to restore original state as best one can. `$original = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);`, do the stuff. `libxml_clear_errors();` `libxml_use_internal_errors($original);`  Working on a non-trivial project and having a method modify global state in an undocumented manner doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 25):

You could also do

```
@$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
```

Comment: Error suppression is not a proper way of dealing with this issue.

Comment: @KlaasSangers Until we have a non-crippled DOM implementation, I'm afraid it is (either through `@` or `libxml_*`)

Comment: yeah, in this specific case, error supression is the best solution, in my opinion. unless you know that the HTML you will be loading, is supposed to be 100% valid HTML per PHP's definition. which in my experience, is never the case.

Comment: @KlaasSangers...why not?

Comment: PHP8 "The @ operator no longer silences fatal errors
It's possible that this change might reveal errors that again were hidden before PHP 8. Make sure to set display_errors=Off on your production servers!"

https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-8

Answer (score 11):

You can filter the errors you get from the parser. As per other answers here, turn off error reporting to the screen, and then iterate through the errors and only show the ones you want:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
// Do your load here
$errors = libxml_get_errors();

foreach ($errors as $error)
{
    /* @var $error LibXMLError */
}
```

Here is a `print_r()` of a single error:

```
LibXMLError Object
(
    [level] => 2
    [code] => 801
    [column] => 17
    [message] => Tag section invalid

    [file] => 
    [line] => 39
)
```

By matching on the `message` and/or the `code`, these can be filtered out quite easily.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a way to kill warnings but not errors. PHP has constants that are supposed to do this, but they don't seem to work. Here is what is SHOULD work, but doesn't because (bug?)....

```
 $doc=new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML("<tagthatdoesnotexist><h1>Hi</h1></tagthatdoesnotexist>", LIBXML_NOWARNING );
 echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

Comment: According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/41845049/937477 that bug has been fixed

Comment: Just to be pedantic, that is not valid HTML5. Custom elements have to have a hyphen in them according to the spec http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#dfn-custom-element-type

Comment: @Greg Good to know. It's just a test to demonstrate the xml parser will recognize the tag is not valid, but ignore it because of the flag.

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$search = array("<header>", "</header>", "<nav>", "</nav>", "<section>", "</section>");
$replace = array("<div>", "</div>","<div>", "</div>", "<div>", "</div>");
$html = str_replace($search, $replace, $html);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

If you need the header tag, change the header with a div tag and use an id. For instance:

```
$search = array("<header>", "</header>");
$replace = array("<div id='header1'>", "</div>");
```

It's not the best solution but depending on the situation it can be useful.

Good luck.

Answer (score -9):

HTML5 tags almost always use attributes such as id, class and so on. So the code for replacing will be:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$search = array(
    "<header", "</header>", 
    "<nav", "</nav>", 
    "<section", "</section>",
    "<article", "</article>",
    "<footer", "</footer>",
    "<aside", "</aside>",
    "<noindex", "</noindex>",
);
$replace = array(
    "<div", "</div>",
    "<div", "</div>", 
    "<div", "</div>",
    "<div", "</div>",
    "<div", "</div>",
    "<div", "</div>",
    "<div", "</div>",
);
$html = str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```