# PHP code to read a web page's source and get attribute from a tag

Tags: php, html, dom

I am reading a source code of a page in PHP. There is an hidden input field `<input type="hidden" name="session_id" value=` in that page.

```
$url = 'URL HERE';
$needle = '<input type="hidden" name="session_id" value=';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
if(strpos($contents, $needle)!== false) {
echo 'found';
} else {
echo 'not found';
}
```

I want to read that hidden field value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By far the best way to do this is with the DOM extension to PHP.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('your URL');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('//input[@name="session_id"]');
if ($elements->length) {
    echo "found: ", $elements->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Comment: +1 just deleted my own answer in favor of the xpath solution :-)

Comment: @imi That is not a valid HTML document. You need to suppress warnings with the same technique I describe [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6090728/417562).

Comment: Its unable to find input[@name="session_id"]

Comment: @imi Are you sure it's present?

Answer (score 3):

I'd look into PHP's native **DOMDocument** extension:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php#example-4867

Comment: ID? Does that work for the `name` attribute as well in DOMDocument?