# Why can't I manipulate an element using PHP DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to perform a simple operation on an element. The HTML file is getting loaded and the id of the element is clearly shown. The error_log included below shows a warning. Since it is a warning, I do expect it wouldn't execute the element manipulation code. I k.now I can suppress the warning Exasperatingly, the echo does not show anywhere.

**PHP**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('../index.html');  
$elem = $doc->getElementById('message');
var_dump( "elem=" . $elem);
if ($result == 1) {
    $elem->innerHTML = 'File uploaded.';
} else {
    $elem->setAttribute("background-color", "red");
    $elem->innerHTML = 'Upload failed.';
}
```

**HTML** (index.html)

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="wtApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <title>Writer's Tryst</title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='css/main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="frainversegment" content="!" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/Hands_of_God_and_Adam.png" />
<!--
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
              document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            try {
                var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-15499108-1");
                    pageTracker._trackPageview();
                } catch (err) { }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Writers-Tryst">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Writers-Tryst</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Writers-Tryst">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a id="homepage" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#writers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"> Writers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#enablers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Enablers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#about" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> About</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> Contact</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#log-in"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Log-In</a></li> 
                            <li><a id="create-account-link" href="#create-account"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Create Account</a></li> 
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" id="drop-toggle-1" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-aria-haspopup="true" data-aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#update-profile">Update profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#manage-uploads">Manage uploads</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li ><a id="reset-pwd-link" href="#reset-pwd"></a></li> 
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div>
            <p id="message"></p>
            <div id="main" class="content">
                <!-- angular templating -->
                <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pages.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> [19-May-2016 13:31:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile():
>   Tag header invalid in ../index.html, line: 42 in
>   /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/writers.php on line 83

Comment: Please explain the reason for the down vote.

Comment: You are not trying to get the live dom of the users browser, right? Because you can't with PHP.

Comment: [PHP DOMDocument errors/warnings on **HTML5 TAGS**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090667/php-domdocument-errors-warnings-on-html5-tags)

Comment: @gant- What is the purpose of these DOM objects if you cannot manipulate the user's DOM?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your don't have the real error here : PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Indeed.

prefer var_dump() your vars than echo, you will avoid that kind of mistakes.

Comment: I tried var_dump too, someone suggested I try echo, but it didn't show up either. I am still in search of the answer to my problem.

Comment: Your are still trying to concatenate your object. var_dump($object); only

Object is a proud member of his cast, he does not like to be assimilated with a common string.

Comment: I think you are still missing the point, although I do like your metaphor. I have taken out the var_dump and am still experiencing the same problem. See @gant comment.

Comment: Well I can't do debug for you but i can say that if i use your html file and this sample code : 

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('../index.html');  
$elem = $doc->getElementById('message');
var_dump($elem);

That does output the object. You can't have a blank page without an error somewhere in logs (if error log is active). Else try putting echoes everywhere in your code until you find the incorrect line.