# PHP LIBXML_NOWARNING not suppressing warnings?

Tags: php, libxml2

Using the LIBXML_NOWARNING options flag doesn't stop wanrings when loading html with PHPDOMDocument->loadHTML. Other constants do work though.

In the example below I add the LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD to prove that the constants are received(stops a doctype from being added).

```
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<tagthatdoesnotexist><h1>Hi</h1></tagthatdoesnotexist>",LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

However, warnings are still generated and output. What am I missing?

Comment: what warnings are generated?

Comment: In the example, <tagdoesnotexist> does not validate as a recognized html tag name. In real world situation the HTML is sometimes malformed in other ways that generates parsing errors.

Answer (score 11):

The [`LIBXML_NOWARNING` option](https://php.net/libxml.constants#constant.libxml-nowarning) is ignored with [`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](https://php.net/DOMDocument.loadHTML) is a bug in PHP (and to be fixed). It has been recently brought up in a [related question *"libxml htmlParseDocument ignoring htmlParseOption flags"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41860683/367456) and filed as [PHP Bug #74004  `LIBXML_NOWARNING` flag ingnored on loadHTML*](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74004).

You can, however, manage the error handling your own until the bug is fixed:

1. Set [`libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`](https://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors) before calling [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](https://php.net/DOMDocument.loadHTML). This will prevent errors from bubbling up to your default error handler. And you can then get at them (if you desire) using other libxml error functions (e.g. [`libxml_get_errors()`](https://php.net/libxml_get_errors)).
2. Make sure you clear the internal error buffer while using the mentioned function. If you don't and you are using this in a long running process, you may find that all your memory is used up.
3. If you want to restore the the default functionality set `libxml_use_internal_errors()`.

Code example:

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();

# clear errors list if any
libxml_clear_errors();

# use internal errors, don't spill out warnings
$previous = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc->loadHTML("<tagthatdoesnotexist><h1>Hi</h1></tagthatdoesnotexist>");
echo $doc->saveHTML();

# clear errors list if any
libxml_clear_errors();

# restore previous behavior
libxml_use_internal_errors($previous);
```

---

### Update

[This bug is fixed now](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=4df993d89da9b78513a75611421e15e100829695).

Comment: +1 For a solution that does prevent warnings being written to output.  However it doesn't truly ignore them, as you point out; it just quietly stores them in memory. I'm miffed I have to store something in memory I explicitly don't care about.

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal: That's not how bounties work. Your answer was and is fine, I just added some of the additional things, there was nothing to add as an answer of it's own. Enjoy the bounty.