# How to get image url by page in PHP

Tags: php

This is my code :

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="link">
    <button type="submit">></button>
</form>
<title>GET IMAGE URL</title>
<?php 
if (!isset($_POST['link'])) exit();
$link = $_POST['link'];
$parse = explode('.html', $link);
echo '<div id="pin" style="float:center"><textarea class="text" cols="110" rows="50">';
for ($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++)
{
    if ($i > 1)
    $link = "$parse[0]-$i.html";
    $get = file_get_contents($link);
    if (preg_match_all('/src="(.*?)"/', $get, $matches))
    {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $content)
        echo $content."\r\n";
    }
}
echo '</textarea>';
```

The page I'm trying to get the img src has 10 to 15 page,so I want my code to get all the img url until the end of the page. How can I do that without the loop?

If I use:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++)
```

this will get only 5 page img urls, but I want to make it get until the end. Then I don't need to edit the loop everytime I submit another URL with a different number of pages.

Comment: from where do u get the number of pages?

Comment: I have to enter to the url to check the number of pages :(

Comment: Can you post a sample url

Comment: Yes ! http://www.xiumm.org/photos/XiuRen-17305-11.html

Comment: and also are these urls saved in database and if yes then when you query them you will get all the urls and then you can run a foreach on the dataset

Comment: You need the count of the pages first e.g. for ($i = 1; $i <=$pagecount; $i++) not enough code to work that work.

Comment: @gabs well,so i have to write a function to count the number of page ?

Comment: @DhavalChheda so i need to get the number of pages in the url too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this

> this will get only 5 page img urls, but I want to make it get until the end. Then I don't need to edit the loop everytime I submit another URL with a different number of pages.

I could understand that your problem is with dynamic number of pages.Your urls have a **next page** link at the bottom

下一页

Identify it and get your images in while loop

```
<?php

// Link given in form
$link = "http://www.xiumm.org/photos/XiuRen-17305.html";
$parse = explode('.html', $link);
$i=1;
// Intialize a boolean 
$nextPageFound = true;


while($nextPageFound) {
    // Construct URL Every time when nextPageFound
    if ($i == 1) {
        $url = "$parse[0].html";
        echo "First Page<br><br>";
     } else {
        $url = "$parse[0]-$i.html";
       }

    // Getting URL Contents
    $get = file_get_contents($url);
    if (preg_match_all('/src="(.*?)"/', $get, $matches))
    {
    // echoing contents
    foreach ($matches[1] as $content)
    echo $content."<br>";
    }
    // check nextPageBtn if available 
    if (strpos($get, '"nextPageBtn"') !== false) {
     $nextPageFound = true;
     // increment +1
     $i++;
    echo "<br>Page $i<br><br>";
    } else {
     $nextPageFound = false;
     echo "THE END";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,i'll give it a try :)

Comment: Well,i'm thinking about,how can i identify the nextpage with that div ?

Comment: hmm..my old code work fines,but when i replace with your code,the error i receive is " Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.xiumm.org/photos/XiuRen-17305-1.html): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15"

Comment: if your link has no number then remove $i

Comment: Well,your code is working,but its still get the original URL img src ,the code can't get the next page img src !

Comment: By the way Photos are really sexy :)

Comment: Haha,you can checkout at my site www.sexyangel.pro !

Comment: I've another problem,what if the url don't have "nextPageBtn" ? Example : Its only contain <a class="a1" href="/item/9375_11.html">下一页</a>. So what should i do ? I'm trying to get with "下一页" and file_get_contents but its not working. I've to use cURL ! Then i've this error "<b>Warning</b>:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\meitulu.php</b> on line <b>57</b><br />" If you need to take a look my code,please reply !

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HTML/XML parser, like [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php), in combination with [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/class.domxpath.php) ([xpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) is query language to query (X)HTML data structures):

```
// create DOMDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// load remote HTML file
$doc->loadHTMLFile( $link );

// create DOMXPath
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );
// fetch all IMG elements that have a src attribute
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//img[@src]' );

// loop trough found IMG elements and echo their src attribute values
for( $i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++ ) {
  echo $nodes->item( $i )->getAttribute( 'src' ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

Regarding the xpath query `//div[contains(@class,'pic_box')]//@src`, mentioned by @Enuma, in the comments:

The resulting `DOMNodeList` of that query will not contain [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/class.domelement.php) objects, but [`DOMAttr`](http://php.net/manual/class.domattr.php) objects, because the query directly asks for attributes, not elements. Since `DOMAttr` represents an attribute and not an element, the method `getAttribute()` does not exist. To get the value of the attribute you have to use the property `DOMAttr->value`.

So, we have to slightly alter the relevant part of our example code from above to:

```
// loop trough found src attributes and echo their value
for( $i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++ ) {
  echo $nodes->item( $i )->value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Putting it all together, our example code then becomes:

```
// create DOMDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// load remote HTML file
$doc->loadHTMLFile( $link );

// create DOMXPath
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );
// fetch all src attributes that are descendants of div.pic_box 
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//div[contains(@class,'pic_box')]//@src' );

// loop trough found src attributes and echo their value
for( $i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++ ) {
  echo $nodes->item( $i )->value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

<sup>PS.: In order for `DOMDocument` to be able to load remote files, I believe some php config setting may be required to be set, which I don't know off the top of my head, right now. But since it already appeared to be working for @Enuma, it's not actually relevant now. Perhaps I'll look them up later.</sup>

Comment: I've tried your solutions,but then,its give me this error "<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Unexpected end tag : div in http://www.xiumm.org/photos/XiuRen-17305.html, line: 27 in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
<br />"

Comment: @Enuma Yeah, by default `DOMDocument` is very strict during parsing. The error indicates that the loaded HTML is malformed. I'll update my answer with some optional settings you can pass, to have `DOMDocument` ignore parsing errors.

Comment: this is my query to get the correct url "$x("//div[contains(@class,'pic_box')]//@src")"

Comment: Thank you,i'm waiting for your answer :)

Comment: @Enuma I've updated my answer. Try it out and see if it works. I have to go now, so I'll come back later today, if you have any more questions about my answer. Good luck, in the meantime!

Comment: Thanks but i can't replace your query with the query i use to get the url img. My query is "//div[contains(@class,'pic_box')]//@src"

Comment: Do you have any suggest about my xquery ? Because in chrome developers tools,i can run it and its working fine !

Comment: @Enuma I see you've already found your answer. Also, it appears I've completely misinterpreted your question, haven't I? I thought you had trouble retrieving a variable amount of images from one page, but it appears you want to retrieve a variable amount of pages, correct? Anyway, I've adjusted my answer to address your comments to my answer.

Comment: Yeah and i think i want both,one page and multi pages !

Comment: I'm using $doc->loadHTMLFile( $link, LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_ERR_NONE | LIBXML_ERR_FATAL ); And the error still appear. :(

Comment: I've success load without error with this : libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile($link);

Comment: @Enuma Ah, right. That appears to be a better way to suppress errors, yes. I'm not sure why my suggested use of constants are not working, the way I expected. I just found out they're not working for me either, when I thought they should work. Sorry about that. (I've just started a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41844778), hoping this gets resolved). In the meantime, make sure you also call `libxml_clear_errors()` each time you are done with `$doc` (if your script uses `$doc` multiple times or is a long-running script). This removes any buffered errors from memory.

Comment: All right then ! I'll include "libxml_clear_errors()" in my source ! Now i've a combination of XPath Query,cURL and DOM. :)

Comment: Could you take a look at my other question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014457/how-to-login-with-curl-and-use-regex