# PHP - html DOM parse - add html content between <video> tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

i like to transform html `<video>` to amp `<amp-video>`, my problem is the **fallback-text if HTML5 is not supported** by used browser.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Here you can see the fallback-text "Your browser does not support the video tag.". On AMP it looks like:

```
<amp-video width=320 height=240 src="https://yourhost.com/videos/movie.mp4"
    poster="movie-poster.jpg">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="movie.mp4">
  <source type="video/ogg" src="movie.ogg">
  <div fallback><p>
    Your browser doesn’t support HTML5 video
  </p></div>
</amp-video>
```

You see, the fallback-text is surrounded by `<div fallback><p>` and `</p></div>`.
**The goal is to add this surrounding tags**.

My code so far is:

```
<?php
    $html = '<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $checks = $dom->getElementsByTagName('video');
    if ($checks != '') {
       foreach ($checks as $check) {
           echo $check->textContent;
       }
    }
?>
```

As you see, I can echo the fallback text, but I have no idea how to add the surrounding tags. `preg_replace` is not possible...

Thanks in advance.

Andreas

P.S.: Sorry for bad english, no native speaker ;-)

---

some progress ;-)

With second DOM I extracted the video-tag as string and try to modify with str_replace. When string is modified I want to "write it back to $check...

the str_replace with $fallbacktext didn't work (maybe a decoding problem?)

My code for now is:

```
<?php
$html = '<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$checks = $dom->getElementsByTagName('video');
if ($checks != '') {
   foreach ($checks as $check) {

    $newdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $cloned = $check->cloneNode(TRUE);
    $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));

    $fallback = $newdoc->saveHTML();   
    $fallbacktext = strip_tags($fallback);
    echo $fallbacktext;
    echo $fallback;

    //$fallbacktext = "Your browser does not support the video tag.";

    echo str_replace($fallbacktext,'hello',$fallback);

   }
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();

//echo $html;

?>
```

Any ideas?

Andreas

Comment: I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6090728/5873008) and it worked. Demo: [https://eval.in/774781](https://eval.in/774781) but you will need to do some work to do what you need to do.

Comment: @alistaircol: I'm sorry, you don't understand my problem... I want to surround the fallback-text with the div and p tags as you can see in amp-video example...