# Cakephp DomDocument works in a file and doesnt in other file

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, domdocument

I have the file code.php in the js folder of my Cakephp.

I also have the file resultcontroller in the folder src/controller/resultcontroller.php

Inside my code.php file:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
...
?>
```

Inside my controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;
...
Class ResultController extendes Controller{
...
public function littlebutton()
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
    ...
    }
...
```

When i run the app, if i call the function littlebutton it give me the error: ERROR:Class App/Controller/DOMDocument not found.
When i run the app and call the code.php file (which is called with an ajax call) it works fine.

I have 2 doubts.

One is why it works with one file and doesn't work with the other? I don't do any call to any class in my code.php file and it works so i expected to do so in the controller.

Second, i read that DOMDocument is included in the php and i dont need to do anything to make it work. And now i don't know.

Please could someone give me some advise? Thank you.

Comment: Namespace.  Use `new \DOMDocument()` (backslash at front) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: I wrote $dom=new \DOMDocument(); and now it gives me several warnings that look almost the same as: Warning (2): DOMDocument::loadHTML() [<a href='http://php.net/domdocument.loadhtml'>domdocument.loadhtml</a>]: Tag svg invalid in Entity, line: 89 [APP/Controller\ResultController.php, line 11696]

Comment: Totally separate issue... First solved, now read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090667/php-domdocument-errors-warnings-on-html5-tags