# Why <picture> source is not downloaded for offline download

Tags: php, html, image, download, concrete5

I'm working on downloading a website for offline viewing, and the images on the website are written inside the `<picture></picture>` element.

When I download a page using the browser or using a website download software, the images are not downloaded.

For example, this image

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="thumb1.jpg" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="thumb2.jpg" media="(min-width: 992px)">
    <source srcset="thumb3.jpg" media="(min-width: 600px)">
    <source srcset="thumb4.jpg" media="(min-width: 320px)">

    <img src="main-image.jpg">
</picture>
```

The browser downloads the main-image.jpg `img` but it doesn't download the `source` images thumb1.jpg, thumb2.jpg, etc.. and this results in that all images are not showing after downloading the page.

Why is that? Why doesn't the browser downloads the `source` images?

The website is built on a php CMS called Concrete5 so the html code gets generated and I can't change the generated html. The website is [http://www.exrx.net/concrete](http://www.exrx.net/concrete/)

Is there a solution for this problem? Is there a software free/paid to accomplish this task?

I tried a software called HTTrack, and Getleft. They both are behaving the same way as the browser.

Comment: I edited my answer. With this solution you will get all image paths found on source tags.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a solution for this problem? Is there a software free/paid to accomplish this task?

I do not know a tool which will also download files found on source tags.

**Edit 02**

With following snippet you will grab all images:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.exrx.net/concrete/');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$imgs = [];
$pictures = $doc->getElementsByTagName('picture');
foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
    $img = [];
    $img[] = $picture->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    $sources = $picture->getElementsByTagName('source');
    foreach ($sources as $source) {
        $img[] = $source->getAttribute('srcset');
    }
    $imgs[] = $img;
}
```

This will produce:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => path/to/file/i1-the original-img-tag-image.gif
            [1] => path/to/file/i2.png
            [2] => path/to/file/i3.png
            [3] => path/to/file/i4.png
            [4] => path/to/file/i5.png
        )
    ...
)
```

These images can then be replaced.

Src:
- [libxml_use_internal_errors() on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090667/php-domdocument-errors-warnings-on-html5-tags#6090728)
- [DOM on php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Thank you very much, your first solution sounds more doable to me than the other. You said  "Then remove the `new \HtmlObject\Image()` and replace it with your own tag". I'm new to concrete5 what should I replace `$tag` variable with?

Comment: Is this also applied to images placed inside the content block? because 90% of the images on the website are used inside content blocks, and the few others in Image block.

Comment: @Tarek Mostafa: `Is this also applied to images placed inside the content block?` - No, if you use the default core `content block` then you will get a `picture` tag with a single `img` tag.

Comment: @Tarek Mostafa: For your second question `... what should I replace ...` I actualized the answer.

Comment: Hi. I tried your code but it gave me many errors one of them was `Call to a member function getThumbnail() on null` and `Call to a member function alt() on string`.. But even if the code works you say it will not affect the content block which is 90% of the problem

Comment: @Tarek Mostafa: It will not affect the content block because the content block does not have any source tags. Therefor you will not have your problem describen in your question. - I will have a look for your errors in 2.5h, after my work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think there's something wrong then because all images placed in content blocks have the `source` tag, you can check the home page http://www.exrx.net/concrete and look in the developer tools, you will see they have `source` tags. We are using the Fruitful theme, could the theme be the problem here? thanks for your time.