# why does a <script> tag stop domdocument() parsing?

Tags: php, domdocument

In the following code, the seemingly innocuous introduction of a script tag containing an empty div causes parsing to fail. (Using an empty script tag causes no problem.) $html1 gets parsed properly, retrieving the values of the two spans:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
)
```

whereas $html2 does not get parsed properly, retrieving only the span preceding the script tag:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
)
```

Why does this happen? With errors turned on I get two errors, "Unexpected end tag : script" and "Unexpected end tag : div" but I do not know why these are unexpected.

```
<?php

$html1 = <<<EOT


<div class="productList"> 

    <span>test1</span>

    <div></div>

    <span>test2</span>

</div>

EOT;

$html2 = <<<EOT

<div class="productList"> 

    <span>test1</span>

    <script> 

        <div></div>

    </script> 

    <span>test2</span>

</div>

EOT;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html1);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$titles_nodeList = $xpath->query('//div[@class="productList"]/span');

foreach ($titles_nodeList as $title) {
    $titles[] = $title->nodeValue;
}

echo("<p>titles without script tag and div</p>");
echo("<pre>");
print_r($titles);
echo("</pre>");

unset($titles);

$dom->loadhtml($html2);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$titles_nodeList = $xpath->query('//div[@class="productList"]/span');

foreach ($titles_nodeList as $title) {
    $titles[] = $title->nodeValue;
}

echo("<p>titles with script tag and div</p>");
echo("<pre>");
print_r($titles);
echo("</pre>");

?>
```

Comment: You might find something useful in this question: [DOM parser that allows HTML5-style </ in <script> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029341/dom-parser-that-allows-html5-style-in-script-tag).

Comment: @Paul DelRe indeed that looks like the same problem, which he solved by using a different DOM parser. I guess my choice is between doing that or just using a regex to remove the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

A div doesn't belong inside a script tag.  Javascript belongs inside a script tag.

Take the div out of the script tag and it should be fine.

Comment: My problem is that I have no control over the html to be parsed, and this html contains divs inside scripts. I'm wondering if the only way to get it to work is to use a hack like removing the scripts with a regex before parsing.

Answer (score -1):

The trick is simple, change `loadHTML` to `loadXML` with one condition,
the HTML string has to be always well-formed

```
$dom->loadXML($html2);
```