# Strange behaviour in Chrome when using document.write for Scripts in iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, document.write

I have the following javascript:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src='javascript:""';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
doc.open();
doc.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />');
doc.write('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=db16ef7a3fac" />');
doc.write('<script type="text/javascript">;</' + 'script>');
doc.write('<title>test</title></head><body><br>test</body></html>');
doc.close();
console.log(doc.body);
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(doc.body);
}, 1000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4gwA/1/), open your console first

If I execute it in Firefox, it dumps `<body>` properly two times.

If I execute it in Chrome, it displays first `null`, then `<body>`. However, If I execute it then again, Chrome also displays `<body>` twice.

If you look at `doc.childNodes` when `body` is `null`, you see that chrome has somehow stopped processing the HTML string right after the `</script>`, therefore the body is not set.

The problem only occurs if the `<link>` tag is present. If I comment out this line, it works properly.

Can you reproduce the problem with chrome? Is there a way to force Chrome to synchronously process the HTML string?

**Edit:** I just fixed the fiddle, it had the css line commented out.

Comment: have you tried to run this code on IE by decreasing its security and allowing the scripts..

Comment: No, I did not check IE. Firefox works, but I have it to work in Chrome. Btw, the script is executed, but everything *after* the script tag is ignored.

Comment: check every  line by placing  alert('')in between lines

Comment: Every line executes successfully, there are no Errors and the last line is obviously reached (otherwise nothing would be written to console.log)

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOM parser that allows HTML5-style </ in <script> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029341/dom-parser-that-allows-html5-style-in-script-tag)

Comment: @PaulSweatte I changed the code to `<' + '/script>'` and still the same. I now guess that chrome parses the HTML asynchronously, and `doc.write` returns before the HTML has been parsed. But it's no longer an issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad it's no longer an issue. The Unicode escape of the backslash, `<script type="text/javascript">;<\u002Fscript>` is another workaround which should work.

Comment: There's a [great article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/etago) which covers this issue in detail for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode escape of the backslash should work:

```
doc.write('<script type="text/javascript"><\u002Fscript>')
```

Use `try/catch` to escape the semicolon:

```
try{;}catch(e){}
```

Use `appendChild` or other DOM methods as a better alternative.

**References**

- [The end-tag open (ETAGO) delimiter](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/etago)

Comment: As I wrote in the comments, that did not help. Note that I already split up the close tag in my code. The cause is something more subtle, probably a concurrency problem.

Comment: I used the Unicode escape, not the string split. In the comments, referenced two links, one with several PHP specific answers, another with JavaScript DOM history. Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4gwA/4/) as well.

Comment: In your fiddle, you removed the semicolon in the scipt tag. If I add id back, I get the problem back. If I remove the semicolon in my code, the problem goes away. The unicode escaping makes no difference; only the empty script tag does because it eliminates its semantics.

Comment: You can also use `try{;}catch(e){}` as an alternative to eval the semicolon safely.

Comment: It was code to initialize an iframe. I fixed it by appending the resources with DOM instead of `document.write`.`