# DOMDocument issues: Escaping attributes and removing tags from javascript

Tags: html, dom, escaping, domdocument

I am not fan of DOMDocument because I believe it is not very good for real world usages. Yet in current project I need to replace all texts in a page (which I don't have access to source code) with other strings (some sort of translation); so I need to use it.

I tried doing this with DOMDocument and I didn't received the expected result. Here is the code I use:

```
function Translate_DoHTML($body, $replaceArray){
    if ($replaceArray && is_array($replaceArray) && count($replaceArray) > 0){
        $body2 = mb_convert_encoding($body, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->resolveExternals = false;
        $doc->substituteEntities = false;
        $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
        if (@$doc->loadHTML($body2)){
            Translate_DoHTML_Process($doc, $replaceArray);
            $body = $doc->saveHTML();
        }
    }
    return $body;
}

function Translate_DoHTML_Process($node, $replaceRules){
    if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $nodes = array();
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode)
            $nodes[] = $childNode;
        foreach ($nodes as $childNode)
            if ($childNode instanceof DOMText) {
                if (trim($childNode->wholeText)){
                    $text = str_ireplace(array_keys($replaceRules), array_values($replaceRules), $childNode->wholeText);
                    $node->replaceChild(new DOMText($text),$childNode);
                }
            }else
                Translate_DoHTML_Process($childNode, $replaceRules);
    }
}
```

And here are the problems:

- Escaping attributes: There are data-X attributes in file that become escaped. This is not a major problem but it would be great if I could disable this behavior.

Before DOM:

```
data-link-content="         <a class=&quot;submenuitem&quot; href=&quot
```

After DOM:

```
data-link-content='         &lt;a class="submenuitem" href="
```

- Removing of closing tags in javascript:
  This is actually the main problem for me here. I don't know for what reason in the world DOMDocument may see any need to remove these tags. But it do. As you can clearly see in below example it remove closing tags in java-script string. It also removed last part of script. It seems like DOMDocument parse the java-script inside. Maybe because there is no CDATA tag? But any way it is HTML and we don't need CDDATA in HTML. I thought CDATA is for xHTML. Also I have no way to add CDDATA here. So can I ask it to not parse script tags?

Before DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.write('<video src="http://x.webm"><p>You will need to <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" target="_blank">Install</a> the latest Flash plugin to view this page properly.</p></video>');  </script>
```

After DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.write('<video src="http://x.webm"><p>You will need to <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" target="_blank">Install the latest Flash plugin to view this page properly.</script>
```

If there is no way for me to prevent these things, is there any way that I can port this code to SimpleHTMLDOM?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my search, reason of the second problem is actually what "Alex" told us in this question: [DOM parser that allows HTML5-style </ in <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029341/dom-parser-that-allows-html5-style-in-script-tag)

But based on their research there is no good parser out there capable of understanding today's HTML. Also, html5lib's last update was 2 years ago and it failed to work in real world situations based on my tests.

So I had only one way to solve the second problem. RegEx. Here is the code I use:

```
function Translate_DoHTML_GetScripts($body){
    $res = array();
    if (preg_match_all('/<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/m', $body, $matches) && is_array($matches) && isset($matches[0])){
        foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match)
            $res["<!-- __SCRIPTBUGFIXER_PLACEHOLDER".$key."__ -->"] = $match;
        $body = str_ireplace(array_values($res), array_keys($res), $body);
    }
    return array('Body' => $body, 'Scripts' => $res);
}

function Translate_DoHTML_SetScripts($body, $scripts){
    return str_ireplace(array_keys($scripts), array_values($scripts), $body);
}
```

Using above two functions I will remove any script from HTML so I can use DomDocument to do my works. Then again at the end, I will add them back exactly where they were.

Yet I am not sure if regex is fast enough for this.

And don't tell me to not use RegEx for HTML. I know that HTML is not a regular language and so on; but if you read the problem your self, you will suggest the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , and replace line content ;

```
$body2 = mb_convert_encoding($body, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

to ;

```
$body2 = convertor($body);
```

and insert in your code ;

```
function convertor($ToConvert)
    {
        $FromConvert = html_entity_decode($ToConvert,ENT_QUOTES,'ISO-8859-1');
        $Convert = mb_convert_encoding($FromConvert, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
        return ltrim($Convert); 
    }
```

But use the right encoding in the context.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Made the things worse. :D Currently it render data attributes and also didn't solved any problem. Actually problem is not encoding. It is how DomDocument parse HTML.