# DOMDocument stripping tags from inline scripts PHP

Tags: javascript, php, domdocument

This is a strange one but looks like $dom->saveHTML() is stripping tags from inline javascript

```
$domStr = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>my page</title>
        <script>
            var elem = "<div>some content</div>";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            MY PAGE
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
';
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);//prevents tags in js from throwing errors; see php.net manual
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace  = true;

    $doc->loadHTML($domStr);
    echo $doc->saveHTML();
exit;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad59a2a1016b2128e437ef61dbe00f1c511bff8d

if you use libxml_use_internal_errors(true); you will not see what is wrong but if removed you get

```
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div
```

Same thing happens with

```
$doc->formatOutput = false;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug of DomDocument.

You have to escape the closing tag of HTML in JS or it gets misinterpreted.

This should work
`var elem = "<div>some content<\/div>";`

Alternatively, if you pass option 1 to the loadHtml the parser will ignore it.

In a bit of an oddity 1 can mean both LIBXML_SCHEMA_CREATE and LIBXML_ERR_WARNING as these two predefined constants have the same value. Presumably it is meant to be LIBXML_SCHEMA_CREATE which does the following "Create default/fixed value nodes during XSD schema validation".

Answer (score 0):

I've avoided this by *not* including any HTML in my inline JavaScript. Instead, I've added `<template>` elements containing the HTML string I want to manipulate in JS, and then I read that dynamically at runtime. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>my page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            MY PAGE
        </div>

        <template id="content-template">
            <div>some content</div>
        </template>

        <script>
            var elem = document.getElementById('content-template').innerHTML;
            ...
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the opening `<html>` tag right after the `DOCTYPE` declaration.

Comment: same with it , code edited
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad59a2a1016b2128e437ef61dbe00f1c511bff8d

Comment: That `<script>` tag's content in the `<head>` is messing it up.

Comment: that is the point of the use , we need to get the scripts in the head

Comment: bud , thnx for trying but that is not actual script , I need to consolidate multiple scripts on page and cant hack them in order to do so. I must get the actual scripts. point is that there is a bug because of libxml2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029341/dom-parser-that-allows-html5-style-in-script-tag

Comment: Well then just use `<script src="path_to_your_script"></script>` ?

Comment: Well, what do ya know, you don't even need to replace the thing, just escape the closing tags. Look here and open the console panel to view the output: http://codepad.viper-7.com/aX3HAc