# How to use PHP DomDocument when script elements contain HTML?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I am trying to download a site for offline viewing and this is requiring me to do a number of DOM manipulations (trust me, wget just is not doing what I need to do...).

**I am finding that webpages containing tags with unusual text content is throwing saveHTML off**.

For some url, if I  use curl to read the page and output as

```
echo $contents;
```

then all is well.

For instance, there is a section of the page containing the following source:

```
<div id="area2516" class="component interaction_component float-none clear-none ">
    <div id="area2516">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.bm = window.bm || {};
            bm.data = bm.data || [];
            bm.data['area2516'] = {};
        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/somecss.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="somejs.js">
        </script>

    <script class="main-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div class="content_area">
                <div class="bg_image cf"></div>
                    {{#each rollovers}}
                <div class="rollover_content" style="left: {{x}}; top: {{y}}; display: none;" data-rollover-id="{{id}}">
                    {{{this.content}}}
                </div>
                {{/each}}
                </div>
                <div class="rollover_links">
                    <ul>
                        {{#each rollovers}}
                        <li>
                            <a class="rollover_link" href="#" data-rollover-id="{{id}}">
                                {{{link}}}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            bm.data['area2516'].assets = {};
            bm.data['area2516'].initial_json = '';
        </script>
```

as seen from the above echo following the curl response.

Now, if I do this

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($contents);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

**the HTML gets messed up**, such that above now becomes this:

```
<div id="area2516" class="component interaction_component float-none clear-none ">
<div id="area2516">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.bm = window.bm || {};
        bm.data = bm.data || [];
        bm.data['area2516'] = {};
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/somecss.css"> . 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/somejs.js"></script>
    <script class="main-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="content_area">
            <div class="bg_image cf">
    </script>
            </div>
            {{#each rollovers}}
            <div class="rollover_content" style="left: {{x}}; top: {{y}}; display: none;" data-rollover-id="{{id}}">
              {{{this.content}}}
            </div>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
        <div class="rollover_links">
          <ul>
            {{#each rollovers}}
              <li>
                <a class="rollover_link" href="#" data-rollover-id="{{id}}">
                  {{{link}}}
                </a>
              </li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        bm.data['area2516'].assets = {};
        bm.data['area2516'].initial_json = '';
      </script>
```

Sorry about the formatting, this new editor is pretty annoying. The point is, **you can see some pretty major differences, and I am not sure how saveHTML is causing this modification to the source**. I suspect it had something to do with encoding and the peculiarity of these double and triple braces used by the templating system, but despite attempts to use various encoding parameters, I am getting the same result. Then I thought maybe has something to do with special chars, escaping, but I am just not sure what function(s) are needed to stop saveHTML from messing up the output.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Looks lite a SPA JS site, possibly running Vue - I think I've seen them using a Mustache-syntax on templates.. Fortunately that template engine has been ported to basically everything, you'll find it here:

 https://mustache.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Per the HTML 4 specification you can't put arbitrary text into a `<script>` element. (Although this [is possible in HTML 5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements), the `libxml` parser included with PHP is not that new.)

If you properly escape the contents of the element, your code should work as expected.

```
$content = <<< HTML
<div id="area2516" class="component interaction_component float-none clear-none ">
    <div id="area2516">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.bm = window.bm || {};
            bm.data = bm.data || [];
            bm.data['area2516'] = {};
        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/somecss.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="somejs.js">
        </script>

    <script class="main-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            &lt;div class="content_area"&gt;
                &lt;div class="bg_image cf"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
                    {{#each rollovers}}
                &lt;div class="rollover_content" style="left: {{x}}; top: {{y}}; display: none;" data-rollover-id="{{id}}"&gt;
                    {{{this.content}}}
                &lt;/div&gt;
                {{/each}}
                &lt;/div&gt;
                &lt;div class="rollover_links"&gt;
                    &lt;ul&gt;
                        {{#each rollovers}}
                        &lt;li&gt;
                            &lt;a class="rollover_link" href="#" data-rollover-id="{{id}}"&gt;
                                {{{link}}}
                            &lt;/a&gt;
                        &lt;/li&gt;
                        {{/each}}
                    &lt;/ul&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            bm.data['area2516'].assets = {};
            bm.data['area2516'].initial_json = '';
        </script>
HTML;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD|LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

The output is as expected:

```
<div id="area2516" class="component interaction_component float-none clear-none ">
    <div id="area2516">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.bm = window.bm || {};
            bm.data = bm.data || [];
            bm.data['area2516'] = {};
        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/somecss.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="somejs.js">
        </script>

    <script class="main-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            &lt;div class="content_area"&gt;
                &lt;div class="bg_image cf"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
                    {{#each rollovers}}
                &lt;div class="rollover_content" style="left: {{x}}; top: {{y}}; display: none;" data-rollover-id="{{id}}"&gt;
                    {{{this.content}}}
                &lt;/div&gt;
                {{/each}}
                &lt;/div&gt;
                &lt;div class="rollover_links"&gt;
                    &lt;ul&gt;
                        {{#each rollovers}}
                        &lt;li&gt;
                            &lt;a class="rollover_link" href="#" data-rollover-id="{{id}}"&gt;
                                {{{link}}}
                            &lt;/a&gt;
                        &lt;/li&gt;
                        {{/each}}
                    &lt;/ul&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            bm.data['area2516'].assets = {};
            bm.data['area2516'].initial_json = '';
        </script></div></div>
```

Note your HTML is invalid in other ways; repeated `id` attributes and missing closing elements.

Comment: Not sure how to escape the chars in this way only for script inner content, but I came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029341/dom-parser-that-allows-html5-style-in-script-tag and it seems to be working...need to test to confirm once I have the rest of the page ready to check. thanks

Answer (score 0):

the input does not even look alike `HTML`, but alike a [Twig](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig) (or similar) template ...

which would need to be pushed through a template engine first, in order to get `HTML` output;

unless passing `(array) $rollovers` ...this will not yield the desired results, for certain.

if these aren't your own template files, you might be downloading the wrong `URL` ...

and someone on the other side has forgotten to prevent access to the templates.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with loadHTML vs loadXML? The template system is javascript Handlebars from what I can tell. I think the site will load locally for me if I can just get the DOMDocument tools to leave everything untouched except for the src and href attributes that I am modifying. thanks, Brian