# Error while removing an element from XML via PHP functions

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to Delete a user with particular ID from an xml file but facing following error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   DOMNode::removeChild() must be an
>   instance of DOMNode, null given in
>   delUser.php

**XML file:**

```
<currentUsers>  
<user id="101" firstName="Klashinkof" p2p="Yes" priority="Low"/>    
<user id="102" firstName="John" p2p="Yes" priority="High"/> 
</currentUsers>
```

**code:**

```
  <?php
     $id=101; //Test

// SETUP $doc
$doc = new DomDocument("1.0");
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$doc->validateOnParse = true; 
$doc->Load('currUsers.xml');

//REMOVE ID
    $user= $doc->getElementByID($id);
    $users= $doc->documentElement;

    if ($oldPerson = $users->removeChild($user)) {
        // worked
        echo "DELETED user {$id}";
        } else {
        return "Couldn't remove $id listing";
    }
$doc->save(curr.xml); 
?>
```

Comment: `DOMDocument::getElementById` -> Returns the DOMElement or NULL if the element is not found. So it looks like `$doc->getElementByID($id);` can't find the element by id .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
$doc->getElementById($id);
```

returns `NULL`. You do not have a schema or DTD attached, so the id attribute is not a valid ID attribute in the XML sense. Thus, it cannot be found by `getElementById`. In addition, IDs may not start with a digit.

Either use XPath, e.g.

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$node = $xp->query("//*[@id='$id']")->item(0);
```

or change the id attribute to `xml:id`, but then you will also have to use a valid ID attribute value.

Once you fetched the node, the easiest way to remove it is to fetch the `parentNode` from it, e.g.

```
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

Further details in [Simplify PHP DOM XML parsing - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405117/simplify-php-dom-xml-parsing-how/3405651#3405651)

Answer (score 0):

<s>`getElementByID()` take a string as parameter as [shown on the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.getelementbyid.php).</s>

So it should be `$id="101";`

<s>Plus, you should have a **check** before using `removeChild()` like `if(!is_null($user)){...}`</s>

@Gordon's solution is faster but if you don't *understand* XPATH (which you should learn), you can use this :

```
$users = $doc->getElementsByTagName('user');
foreach($users as $user){
   if($user->hasAttribute('id') && $user->getAttribute('id') == $id){
      $user->parentNode->removeChild($user);
   }
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://codepad.org/ubQuBtFI)

Comment: @baltusaj : Actually, I wasn't right. Now it's working (another solution without XPATH)