# PHP XML DOM getElementById

Tags: php, xml, dom, getelementbyid

I need to pick one tag from xml file and insert another tag before this tag. I'm doing this with method `insertBefore` in DOM, but the problem is, that if I want pick the tag before I want to add the another tag by method `getElementById`, it doesn't work.
It writes "using non-object". This is how the tag looks:

```
<item id="Flow_0" href="Flow_0.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
```

Somewhere I read that it must look like this, but I can't edit all files:

```
<item xml:id="Flow_0" href="Flow_0.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
```

Have you got any idea how to do that?

Comment: *(related)* [Simplify PHP DOM XMP Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405117/simplify-php-dom-xml-parsing-how/3405651#3405651) has an explanation why `getElementById` doesnt work. In a nutshell: when there is no DTD or Schema that [defines id to be an IDAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domattr.isid.php), its not an ID in the ID sense but just an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common workaround is to use XPath to get the element.

```
$item = $xpath->query('//item[@id="Flow_0"]')->item(0);
```