# DOMDocument::getElementById returns NULL

Tags: php, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplify PHP DOM XML parsing - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405117/simplify-php-dom-xml-parsing-how)

Here is my XML (c.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <head>
        <title id="title">Hello</title>
    </head>
</root>
```

What I do:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->load('./c.xml');

var_dump($dom->getElementById('title'));die(); // returns NULL
```

What is the problem here&?

**UPD**

`$dom->validate();` returns `DOMDocument::validate(): no DTD found!`

Comment: Can you run `$dom->validate() ` on your code?

Comment: @Gordon is there to use `id` but not `xml:id`? Maybe I should add `xml:ns` or something to the root element?

Comment: you dont need to add a namespace to use `xml:id`. See the linked dupe for explanations about it and http://codepad.org/Pn8NmcV6 for proof.

Comment: I see. So there is no workaround to use exactly `id`, nor `xml:id`?

Comment: well, this *is* a workaround. The alternative is to have a full fledged DTD or a Schema file or to fetch all the id attributes like if they were regular attributes, e.g. `//@id` and then use `setIdAttribute` on them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [The Manual](http://php.net/domdocument.getelementbyid) explains why this may happen

> For this function to work, you will need either to set some ID attributes with DOMElement->setIdAttribute() or a DTD which defines an attribute to be of type ID. In the later case, you will need to validate your document with DOMDocument->validate() or DOMDocument->validateOnParse before using this function.

Potential fixes:

1. Call `$dom->validate();`, afterwards you can use `$dom->getElementById()`, regardless of the errors for some reason.
2. Use XPath if you don't feel like validating:

   `$x = new DOMXPath($dom);`

   `$el = $x->query("//*[@id='title']")->item(0);` //Look for id=title

Example of using a custom DTD:

```
$dtd = '<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>
        <!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>';

$systemId = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($dtd);

$creator = new DOMImplementation;
$doctype = $creator->createDocumentType($root, null, $systemId); //Based on your DTD from above
```

Comment: +1, only `$dom->validate()` needs to see an appropriate DTD in order to work.

Comment: I saw this in DOCS. So I should put attach `DTD` file to my XML. How to do it? Is there any "default" DTD's?

Comment: +1 for 'Use XPath if you don't feel like validating'