# PHP document model: Finding an element in a composed HTML document

Tags: php, dom

I have a library that composes HTML elements using the DOM classes. I want to also use the DOM functionality to go deep into my composed elements and check specific child elements for values.

For example, here's element produced by a class called `YesNoControl`:

```
<div id="yes_no">
  <input id="yes_no_1" name="yes_no" value="1" type="radio"/>
  <label for="yes_no_1">Yes</label>
  <input id="yes_no_2" name="yes_no" value="2" type="radio"/>
  <label for="yes_no_2">No</label>
</div>
```

A PHPUnit test should look something like this:

```
$element = new YesNoControl();

$element_dom = $element->toDOMDocument(); // This method renders the object to a DOMDocument object.
$element_dom->validate();
$this->assertInstanceOf(\\DOMDocument::class, $element_dom);

$input = $element_dom->getElementById('yes_no_1');
$this->assertInstanceOf(\DOMNode::class, $input); 
$this->assertEquals('1', $input->getAttribute('yes_no_1'));
```

The problem is that `$input` always comes back `null`.

In my research, I found that `getElementById()` works only if the document has a DOCTYPE HTML tag. In my builder, I'm creating the document the plain-and-simple way:

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
```

I tried adding the implementation tag to the document directly after creating the document thusly:

```
$implementation = new \DOMImplementation();
$document->appendChild($implementation->createDocumentType('HTML'));
```

However, this produces invalid elements with the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` incorrectly inserted, like this example:

```
<div id="yes_no">
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <input id="yes_no_1" name="yes_no" value="1" type="radio"/>
  <label for="yes_no_1">Yes</label>
  <input id="yes_no_2" name="yes_no" value="2" type="radio"/>
  <label for="yes_no_2">No</label>
</div>
```

I see quite a few answers that mention putting `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` into HTML being interpreted (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144061/using-php-to-get-dom-element)). But I'm not starting from HTML; I'm composing an element and letting the DOM library write the HTML.

I've also tried creating an implementation on the fly, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298899/1905056):

```
$element_dom = $element->toDOMDocument(); // This method renders the object to a DOMDocument object.
$element_dom->validate();

$dtd = '<!ELEMENT input (#PCDATA)>';
$systemId = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($dtd);
$implementation = new \DOMImplementation;
$element_dom->appendChild($$implementation->createDocumentType('HTML', null, $systemId));

$input = $element_dom->getElementById('yes_no_1');
$this->assertInstanceOf(\DOMNode::class, $input); 
// Failed asserting that null is an instance of class "DOMNode".
```

I've also tried using XPath to get the value:

```
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($element_dom);
$input = $xpath->query("//*[@id=yes_no_1]")->item(0);
$this->assertInstanceOf(\DOMNode::class, $input); 
// Failed asserting that null is an instance of class "DOMNode".
```

So far, nothing I have tried is working. How do I need to structure my test so that it can find `yes_no_1`?

Comment: In your XPath version - you need quotes round the value your checking for - `//*[@id='yes_no_1']`

Comment: That resolves the issue. Add your comment as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XPath version - you need quotes round the value your checking for

```
$input = $xpath->query("//*[@id='yes_no_1']")->item(0);
```